# Is it possible to construct a geodesic for an anholonomic system?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics, constrained-dynamics

For anholonomic system, i.e. Gravitation Eq. 9.22

$$[e_\mu, e_\nu] =c_{\mu\nu}^\alpha e_\alpha$$ where $$[e_\mu, e_\nu]\neq 0$$ for some $\mu,\nu$,
[the states of the system dependent on its path.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonholonomic_system)

**Question 1.a:** However, is it still possible to construct some sort of geodesic equation for the anholonomic system? i.e. 
$$\nabla_u v=0$$

**Question 1.b:** If it is possible, how would it be different from the usual geodesic equation, ie. Gravitation Eq. 10.28 
$$\frac{dv^\alpha}{d\lambda}+ \Gamma ^\alpha _{\gamma \beta} v^\gamma \frac{dx^\beta}{d\lambda}=0$$

**Question 2:** Especially, since the solution would be path dependent, what physical meaning would it be carrying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-holonomic *system* is different from a nonholonomic *basis*, which is what MTW refers to.  A non-holonomic basis is simply one which cannot be induced by a coordinate chart (i.e. it cannot be written in the form $\big\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}\big\}$ for some coordinate system $x^\alpha$).  The wiki article you link is talking about something completely  different.

---

> However, is it still possible to construct some sort of geodesic equation for the anholonomic system?

Sure.  It looks basically the same - however, the connection coefficients in a non-coordinate basis are different:

$$\nabla_\mu \mathbf X = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} X^a + \omega_\mu\ ^a_{\ \ b} X^b\right)\mathbf e_a$$

where the vector $\mathbf X$ has been expanded in a non-coordinate basis $\mathbf e_a$.  Contrast this with the expression we get when we write $\mathbf X$ in a coordinate basis:

$$\nabla_\mu \mathbf X = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} X^\nu + X^\sigma\Gamma^\nu_{\mu \sigma}\right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$$

Whereas the $\Gamma$'s are the components of (usually) the Levi-Civita connection, the $\omega$'s are the components of the *spin connection* (at least, they are when the $\mathbf e$'s are [chosen to be orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_connection)).  One can show that

$$\omega_\mu\ ^a_{\ \ b} = e^a_{\ \ \nu} e_b^{\ \ \lambda} \Gamma^\nu_{\mu \lambda} +e_b^{\ \ \lambda} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} e^a_{\ \ \lambda}$$

---

> If it is possible, how would it be different from the usual geodesic equation?

Not much different.  Consider a worldline with components $x^\mu(\lambda)$.  The tangent vector to the worldline can be expressed as

$$\dot{\mathbf x} = \dot x^\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu} = \dot x^\mu e^a_{\ \ \mu} \mathbf e_a \equiv \dot x^a \mathbf e_a$$

where $\dot x^a \equiv e^a_{\ \ \mu} \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}$ is not the time derivative of the coordinate $x^a$ (there *is* no such coordinate!), but rather a linear combination of such time derivatives.  From there, the geodesic equation becomes

$$\ddot x^\mu + \dot x^a \dot x^b \omega^\mu_{\ \ ab} = 0$$

where $\omega^\mu_{\ \ ab} \equiv g^{\mu \nu} g_{ac} \omega_\nu \ ^c_{\ \ b}$

---

> Especially, since the solution would be path dependent, what physical meaning would it be carrying?

In light of the fact that a non-holonomic *system* and a nonholonomic *basis* are completely different things, this question doesn't make sense.  I will say, however, that non-coordinate bases are necessary if you want to consider spinor fields on spacetime, rather than just tensor fields.

---

Example: Consider $\mathbb R^2$, equipped with the Euclidean metric.  In Cartesian coordinates $\{x,y\}$, the coordinate-induced basis vectors are $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right\}$. The metric components in this basis are simply $g_{\mu\nu}=\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1}$, and the connection coefficients $\Gamma^\mu_{\ \ \nu\sigma}$ all vanish.

If we remove the origin from consideration, we can switch to polar coordinates $\{r,\theta\}$ and the corresponding induced basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial r},\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right\}$. Since $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$, we can write

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \cos(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} = -r\sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + r\cos(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = -y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

We have expressed the new basis vectors as linear combinations of the old ones.  We can find the new metric components:
$$g_{rr} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} g_{xx}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} g_{xy}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} g_{yx}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} g_{yy}$$
$$=\cos^2(\theta) (1) + \cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) (0) + \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(0)+ \sin^2(\theta) (1) =1$$
and similarly,
$$g_{r\theta}=g_{\theta r} =0$$
$$g_{\theta\theta} = r$$

We could also find the new connection coefficients; you can find the relatively simple calculation [here](https://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/general-relativity/29-christoffel-symbol-use-case-calculation-in-polar-coordinates).

The key thing to understand is the interplay between the change of *coordinates* and the change of *basis*.  Our procedure from changing the metric components and the connection coefficients from a basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right\}$ to a basis $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial r},\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right\}$ is derived from the corresponding coordinate shift from $\{x,y\}$ to $\{r,\theta\}$. What if we want to use a basis which *cannot* be induced by such a coordinate change?

For instance, consider the *orthonormal polar* basis $\{\mathbf e_r, \mathbf e_\theta\}$, where
$$\mathbf e_r = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \equiv e_r^{\ \ x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + e_r^{\ \ y} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$
$$\mathbf e_\theta = \left(\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \equiv e_\theta^{\ \ x}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + e_\theta^{\ \ y} \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

It is straightforward to show that given some generic smooth function $f$, $[\mathbf e_r,\mathbf e_\theta]f \neq 0$, which means that $\mathbf e_r$ and $\mathbf e_\theta$ **do not commute**.  This is in contrast to $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial r},\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\right\}$ (or indeed, $\left\{\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha},\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\right\}$ for any $\alpha,\beta$) because mixed partial derivatives always commute. It follows that this basis simply does not correspond to any choice of coordinates; by using it, we have decoupled the coordinate system from the tangent vector basis.

Comment: Thank you! However, could you provide some hints over "nonholomonic basis" could not be expressed as in basis $\{\partial_{x^\alpha}\}$? The book didn't mentioned anything about it. Does it mean the basis had to contain factor such as $\delta_{ab}$ or $\partial^2_{x^\alpha}$?

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate I have expanded my answer considerably to give you an example of such a basis.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That was an excellent explanation.